# How to reduce frame rate of animated gif?

Tags: gif, slideshow

I have a gif file of bigger file size. How can I reduce framerate of gif to make it lower file size? 
I know there are lots of online tool available to optimize gif, but they basically reduce the quality and color of gif. I was looking different approach to optimize/slim my gif by reducing framerate. 
Also I need to optimize my gif within target file size. 
If there any software available to do this job

Answer (score 1):

https://ezgif.com/optimize has an option to reduce framerate (Remove every 2nd frame or every 3rd frame).